# Concatenation of textbox values to build SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

This is a basic question, and obviously not a good practice, as it invites SQL injection attacks. But I want to know the role of double quotes within single quotes.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    string ph = "ph";    // consider it is coming from textbox.

    // here one single quote is to make Name a string - why the other double qoute?
    string query = "select * from tblProduct where Name like '"  + ph + "%'";    

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: "and obviously not a good practice" - correct! So why even do it!

Comment: obviously... but let me know how query build?from the starting of double quote to end of double quote how it decides to left the double quote in middle and consider it as a string value?? @MitchWheat

Comment: Unrelated tip: `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are both `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: a string in sql server is surrounded by single quotes; that's it. With that said, use command.Parameters!!!

Comment: i am asking about double quotes within those single quotes,i know in sql server strings are written in single quote, what is the purpose of this("  + ph + ") @MitchWheat

Comment: it's simply C#  string concatenation and should never be done this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding this line

```
string query = "select * from tblProduct where Name like '"  + ph + "%'";
```

You seem to think that the string is being defined as `select * from tblProduct where Name like '"  + ph + "%'`, since the question is asking why there is a double-quote; but it is actually simpler than that. A string goes from double-quote to double-quote (unless using literal strings, but let's keep this simple). That line is simply putting three strings together:

`select * from tblProduct where Name like '` and `ph` (because that is the value inside the ph variable) and `%'`

For example, try changing `string ph="ph";` to be `string ph="hello";` and see what the query looks like.

Comment: great explaination many thanks to you my teacher has never tought me like this.@Richardissimo

Comment: The `ph` used when defining `query` is a reference to the variable with that name, not the literal string with two characters in it. That's why I was suggesting you try changing the value of the variable.